# regular expression for bulgarian mobile phone numbers

Tags: regex

Hello I should think of this regular expression:

The telephone number should begin  with 087 OR 088 OR 089 and then it should be followed by7 digits:
This is what I made but it doesn't work correctly: it accepts only numbers which begin with 089

```
(087)|(088)|(089)[0-9]{7}";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/08[789]\d{7}/
```

that will match `087xxxxxxx`, `088xxxxxxx`, `089xxxxxxx` numbers.

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/gC5wE6)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `/08[7-9][0-9]{7}/` is what you're searching for?

Autopsy:

- `08` - *a literal `08`*
- `[7-9]` - *matches the numbers from 7-9 once*
- `[0-9]{7}` - *matches the numbers from 0-9 repeated exactly 7 times*

That said, you might prefer `/^08[7-9][0-9]{7}$/` if your string is **only** the phone number. (`^`  means "the string MUST start here" and `$` means "the string MUST end here").

Answer (score 0):

Actually that will be far better regex for Bulgarian phone numbers:

```
/(\+)?(359|0)8[789]\d{1}(|-| )\d{3}(|-| )\d{3}/
```

It checks:

1. Phones that start with country code(+359) or 0 instead;
2. if the phone number use delimiters like - or space.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in https://regex101.com and it did not work against my test set. So I tweaked it a little bit with the below regex pattern:

```
^([+]?359)|0?(|-| )8[789]\d{1}(|-| )\d{3}(|-| )\d{3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(((\+|00)359[- ]?)|(0))(8[- ]?[789]([- ]?\d){7})$/gm
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/09wNm7/1).
Like the previous answer, separators (space and dashes) could be in any position. But double separators like `--` are not allowed.
Following samples covered:

- +359882333444
- +359 882 333 444
- +359-882 33-34-44
- +35988 233-3444
- 088 233 3444
- 0882 333-444

White space before and after the string is not accepted.